# Change "This page cannot be displayed" to custom page

Tags: c#, asp.net, browser, offline, display

I wrote an application that loads a page through a webbrowser form. Loading the page is done through webbrowser.navigate in the webbrowser_DocumentCompleted function. This works quite well. But if the application has no network it displays the "This page cannot be displayed" - page. Is it possible to display a custom page instead and if yes - how? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you may perform a network checking at the start of your application and if it fails you may redirect it to your error page?

other way round in your app.config you may use the following code:

```
 <system.web>
<customErrors>
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="error.htm"/>
</customErrors>
```

whenever your application receive http error code 404 it will redirect to error.htm page

Answer (score 0):

Yo can create a Custom Error Page and display it for multiple Error statuses from your `web.config`.

**Custom Error Page:**

When an unhandled exception arises in an ASP.NET application one of three types of error pages is displayed:

- The Exception Details Yellow Screen of Death error page,
- The Runtime Error Yellow Screen of Death error page, or
- A custom error page

By default, all types of errors cause the same custom error page to be displayed. However, you can specify a different custom error page for a specific `HTTP status code` using `<error>` children elements within the `<customErrors>` section. For example, to have a different error page displayed in the event of a page not found error, which has an `HTTP` status code of `404`, update the `<customErrors>` section to include the following markup:

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="~/ErrorPages/Oops.aspx">
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/ErrorPages/404.aspx" />
</customErrors>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to handle your WebBrowser's Navigated method, then try to access the Domain property of the WebBrowser object's Document object. If it can't access the domain (like when the server is down, or doesn't exist), it'll throw an error. Then you just have to catch the error and write your own HTML directly to the WebBrowser's Document object like this:

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_Navigated(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.Navigated

    Dim doc As HtmlDocument = WebBrowser1.Document

    Try
        Dim s As String = doc.Domain
    Catch ex As Exception
        WebBrowser1.Document.Write("<html><body><br/><h1>The site you are trying to reach is offline or hasn't been set up yet. Please contact your system administrator.</h1></body></html>")
    End Try
End Sub
```